# realm objects in a listview deleted by background sync causes crash

Tags: android, multithreading, android-listview, realm

I have a project that displays RealmObjects in a Listview via an adapter. The realm is updated in a SyncAdapter that runs every few minutes.  This pulls data from a server, and updates the realm, which sometimes results in RealmObjects being deleted.  When this background SyncAdapter's sync cycle is complete, it sends a Broadcast which the ListView's hosting activity catches, which causes the activity to re-query realm and re-populate the adapter with the changed data.

The problem is, when a user is scrolling the ListView, the adapter is is fetching fields from the realm objects to build the views.  If the sync runs at that time, and an object is deleted from realm (via the SyncAdapter), the app crashes when trying to build a view from the deleted object.

What is a good pattern for dealing with this case? I thought of adding a realm observer on the UI side, and immediately querying and re-setting the adapter's RealmObject list when that fires, however the race condition would still remain, it would just be a shorter window.

I also thought about setting auto-updates to false on the UI thread's realm, and implementing some logic to manually refresh the UI thread realm when a change is detected.

Any other ideas?

Comment: If your sync adapter run on a background thread. It should be enough to register a ChangeListener on the RealmResults and refresh the ListAdapter when it is triggered. The only time you should run into crashes due to deleted objects is if you keep references to them outside the scope of a refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [common good practice](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture) is to separate models on layer data models and domain models. In your case `Activity` or `Adapter` not need to know about `RealmObject`'s. All returns from the `Realm` shall be converted into `pojo`.

It's normal to have different models, it will give you an advantage thread-safety and it will be easier to change the database, if there is need.

**Datalayer model**

```
public class RealmEvent extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int eventId;
    private String title;

       public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getEventId() {
        return eventId;
    }

    public void setEventId(int eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }

}
```

**Domain model**

```
public class Event {

    private int eventId;
    private String title;

       public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getEventId() {
        return eventId;
    }

    public void setEventId(int eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }

}
```

**Mapper**

```
public class EventMapper {
  public Event map(RealmEvent event) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Perhaps this solution a little impact on performance. But until December 2015 it was the only solution, if you want to work with `RxJava`, so I think the difference will not be strong.